# How do I make my fibonacci sequence go up to n and not over at all

Tags: python, algorithm

Given the positive integer `n` create a list consisting of the portion of the Fibonacci sequence less than or equal to n. For example, if `n is 6`, then the list would be `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]` and if `n is 1`, then the list would be `[0, 1, 1]`.

Currently this is what I have, if `n` equals numbers as 6 or 20 than the Fibonacci sequence goes over `n` e.g `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]` for `n = 6` or `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]` for `n = 20`

this is what I currently have

```
fib = [0,1]

result = 0

while result < n:
    result = fib[-1] + fib[-2]
    fib.append(result)
```

Comment: step manually through your code and you'll understand why...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If you mean you want the last *term* in your list to be less than `n` then the below is valid otherwise the answer by saurabh is correct.

What happens if your in the while loops current iteration and your result is above the limit `n`? You're still going to add it...

Here's a poor man's approach:

```
fib = [0,1]

result = 0
n = 6
while result < n:
    result = fib[-1] + fib[-2]
    if (result < n):
        fib.append(result)
print(fib)
```

For 6: `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]`
For 20: `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]`

Answer (score 0):

```
fib = [0,1]

result = fib[-1] + fib[-2]
while result < n:
    fib.append(result)
    result = fib[-1] + fib[-2]
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Bugs were not using `<=` and computing new result before appending.  This handles all test cases, plus 0 and negative numbers are handled as well:

```
def fib(n):
    if n < 0:                       # if you care about negative numbers.
        return []
    fib = [0]                       # handles n == 0
    result = 1                      # next result for n > 0
    while result <= n:              # handles "...less than or equal to n"
        fib.append(result)
        result = fib[-1] + fib[-2]
    return fib

for i in (-1,0,1,6,20):
    print(i,fib(i))
```

Output:

```
-1 []
0 [0]
1 [0, 1, 1]
6 [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
20 [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you can pop as well.

Here's the code:

```
n = 20
fib = [0, 1]
while fib[-1] <= n:
    fib.append(fib[-2] + fib[-1])
fib.pop()
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your while condition is set against the last number, you should set it against the total no of elements in your list.

```
fib = [0,1]

result = 0
count = 20
while len(fib) < count :
    result = fib[-1] + fib[-2]
    fib.append(result)
print(fib)
print(len(fib))
```

Will give **OP**

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181]
20
```

Answer (score -1):

you just need to have it print:

fib[-2]

this will print the number that was <= n